# how to check if the segmented plane is a real plane

Tags: c++, math, geometry

I'm getting three parameters of a plane, but I need to make sure they define a plane.  Is there a mathematical way to check from the parameters `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` that that equation fits a plane?

Comment: "that that equation fits a plane" - that WHAT equation fits a plane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general plane is given by the equation

```
ax + by + cz = d
```

A valid plane is any where there exists a non-empty, proper subset of ℝ<sup>3</sup> satisfying the equation above.  That is, there exists a set of points (*x*, *y*, *z*) ∈ ℝ<sup>3</sup> which can satisfy the equation, and there are other points in ℝ<sup>3</sup> which cannot satisfy it.

This occurs whenever (*a*<sup>2</sup> + *b*<sup>2</sup> + *c*<sup>2</sup>) > 0, which in turn will occur when at least one of *a*, *b*, and *c* are non-zero.  So, all you need to do is check that at least one of *a*, *b*, and *c* are non-zero.

Comment: I have some coefficients as negative, should I consider that situation as not a plane ?

Comment: @andre No.  At least one of the coefficients has to be non-zero.  There are no other restrictions, and the sign of any non-zero coefficients does not enter into any validity considerations.  The problem occurs only if all coefficients are 0.  When this is the case, the equation becomes degenerate (no points satisfy the equation) if d≠0 or all points in ℝ^3 will satisfy the equation if d=0, which is also fails to define a plane.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you out a bit with your problem. It may not directly answer your question but could lead to such an answer. In one of my older math libraries I do have a class that involves planes in 3D space. This class does use another class that I have Vector3 in which I will not show here but has most the common functions and operations you would find in any Vector class for mathematics.

**Plane Class**

```
#ifndef PLANE_H
#define PLANE_H

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Core.h"

// General Equation Of A Plane
//
// --- Ax + By + Cz + D = 0 ---
//
class Plane {

public:
    bool    _bOk;

private:
    Vector3 _v3Point;
    Vector3 _v3Normal;

public:
    inline Plane();
    inline Plane( Vector3 v3Point, Vector3 v3Normal );
    inline Plane( Vector3 v3Point1, Vector3 v3Point2, Vector3 v3Point3 );

    ~Plane();

    inline Vector3 GetNormal();

}; // Plane

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Plane()
// Constructor - Set Plane To Be Horizontal At Origin With Normal In +Y
inline Plane::Plane() {

    _v3Point  = Vector3( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
    _v3Normal = Vector3( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );

    _bOk = true;

} // Plane

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Plane()
// Constructor - Set Plane To Given Point And Normal
inline Plane::Plane( Vector3 v3Point, Vector3 v3Normal ) {

    _v3Point  = v3Point;
    _v3Normal = v3Normal;

    if ( v3Normal.IsZero() ) {
        _bOk = false;
        return;
    }
    _bOk = true;

    _v3Normal.Normalize();

} // Plane

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Plane()
// Constructor - Define A Plane Given Three Points
inline Plane::Plane( Vector3 v3Point1, Vector3 v3Point2, Vector3 v3Point3) {

    _v3Point = v3Point1;

    // Get Two Vectors From The Given Points
    Vector3 v3Vector1;
    Vector3 v3Vector2;

    v3Vector1 = v3Point3 - v3Point2;
    v3Vector2 = v3Point1 - v3Point2;

    // Get Normal By Crossing The Two Vectors
    _v3Normal = v3Vector1.Cross( v3Vector2 );

    if ( _v3Normal.IsZero() ) {
        _bOk = false;
    }
    _bOk = true;

    _v3Normal.Normalize();

} // Plane

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// GetNormal()
// Return The Normal To The Plane
inline Vector3 Plane::GetNormal() {

    return _v3Normal;

} // Plane

#endif // PLANE_H
```

Hopefully this may give you some insight.